# How can I debug Grunt file paths?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

In my gruntFile.js, I have something like this:

```
  coffee: {
      compileScripts: {
        expand: true,
        flatten: true,
        src: '**/*.coffee',
        dest: '.tmp/scripts',
        ext: '.js'
      }
```

I want to see what path `**/*.coffee` expands to.  Is there a way to print this to the console so I can play around with the asterisks until it's right?

Comment: Hi Kelly, have you tried adding the `--verbose` command line flag?

Comment: I read that but thought it was supposed to go in the Grunt file.  That works.  Thanks!  Want to post an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [grunt.log](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log) documentation, there is a lot of information that becomes available in the terminal if grunt is invoked using the `--verbose` command line option:

```
grunt --verbose
```

In the actual gruntfile, if there's ever anything that you want to output to the console but only when this flag is used, use grunt.verbose instead of grunt.log.

Comment: One more question, jmort.  If I put this: grunt.log.write('**/*.coffee') it prints the string out as text.  Is there a way to get that to print as the expanded path?

Comment: This is where debugging these things can get a little tough, if the author of the Grunt module you're using didn't add any verbose log statements... In these cases, I start simple and move up from there. It might be worth expanding your question to describe in more detail what your file system looks like. Are you trying to target all folders recursively or just one level down? And what behavior is happening that is different from what you expect? Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's an example configuration for my jsdoc builder: `src: ['scripts/**/*.js', 'jasmineTests/spec/**/*.js'],` This searches scripts recursively and jasmineTests/spec subfolders recursively for all js files. Not sure what you're trying to do, but hope this helps!